# Why won't my console show my javsacript variables?

Tags: console

```
async function drawBars() {
  // your code goes here
  //1)Access Data
  const dataset = await d3.json("my_weather_data.json")

  const metricAccessor = d => d.humidity
  const yAccessor = d => d.length

  //2) Create Chart Dimensions
  
  const width = 600

  let dimensions = {
    width: width,
    height: width *.6,
    margin:{
      top: 30,
      right:10,
      bottom: 50,
      left: 50,
    }
  }

  dimensions.boundedWidth = dimensions.width - dimensions.margin.left - dimensions.margin.right
  dimensions.boundedHeight = dimensions.height - dimensions.margin.top - dimensions.margin.bottom

  //3)Draw Canvas
  const wrapper = d3.select("#wrapper")
    .append("svg")
      .attr("width", dimensions.width)
      .attr("height", dimensions.height)

      const bounds = wrapper.append("g")
      .style("transform", `translate(${dimensions.margin.left}px, ${dimensions.margin.top}px)`)
  
      
  //4) Draw Scales
  const xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain(d3.extent(dataset, metricAccessor))
  .range([0, dimensions.boundedWidth])
  .nice()

const binsGenerator = d3.bin()
  .domain(xScale.domain())
  .value(metricAccessor)
  .thresholds(12)

const bins = binsGenerator(dataset)

const yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(bins, yAccessor)])
  .range([dimensions.boundedHeight, 0])
  .nice()
}
 
drawBars()
```

**Code Above. I'm trying to access the variables in the code**

[image]

Hi!When I run console.log(dataset) to access my data on the live server, it shows no error. I defined the dataset as a constant, and an unsure why this error persists.

Comment: Please share your code. It's hard to debug without that. Are you sure you're not declaring these vars inside a closure of some sort in your script, or if you are, you're prefixing them with `window.` to make them global?

Comment: Hi ggorlen! I added my code above. The variables are defined in an async function.

Comment: Yup, that means they're scoped locally to the function, not available on the window. This is a good thing. It might help if you explained why you want to read them on the window -- maybe use your console's debugger if you want to see their values at a certain program point.

Comment: Hi! thank you so much for your response. I wanted to read them onto the window as I'm following a book example as a guide; by reading the console.log(dataset) I should be outputting arrays from the data json file. I'm not sure how the author got the data arrays to show from console.log as the code is the exact same.

Comment: As I mentioned above, `dataset` is inside of the function so you can't access it from the global scope. You could add your `console.log` into the function, attach the data to the window `window.dataset = dataset` (not recommended but lets you do what you're trying to do), or use a debugger to access it.